# How I can make horizontal Table?

Tags: php

Code PHP in lib:

```
$spellquery = doquery("SELECT id,name,type FROM {{table}}","habilidades");
        $userspells = explode(",",$userrow["spells"]);
        $userrow["magiclist"] = "";
        while ($spellrow = mysql_fetch_array($spellquery)) {
            $spell = false;
            foreach($userspells as $a => $b) {
                if ($b == $spellrow["id"]) { $spell = true; }
            }
            if ($spell == true) {
                $userrow["magiclist"] .= "<a href=\"index.php?do=habilidad:".$spellrow["id"]."\"><img border=0 src=\"estilo/imagenes/skills/".$spellrow["name"].".png\" ></a><br />";
            }
        }
        if ($userrow["magiclist"] == "") { $userrow["magiclist"] = "none"; }
```

Code in Template page:

```
 <div>

    {{magiclist}}

    </div>
```

---

Show in page : http://lordehsa.5gbfree.com/estilo/imagenes/skills/out.JPG

i want make this : http://lordehsa.5gbfree.com/estilo/imagenes/skills/out2.jpg

Comment: please show the output html and css, even better if you create a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove `<br />` to show images in a line!

Comment: Ashkan jan ID yahoo dari?